# Clearing/removing all breakpoints

Tags: edebug

Is there a mechanism for clearing all breakpoints (remove instrumentation en masse) so as to avoid the need to manually run `eval-defun` on each instrumented function's definition?

Comment: The code of `edebug-instrument-function` shows that the function is not instrumented if `(get symbol 'edebug)` is a marker and the function is instrumented if `(get symbol 'edebug)` is a cons. Currently your version of `edebug-remove-all-instrumentation` evals defuns of uninstrumented functions if they have been instrumented before.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for the observation!  I've updated the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consensus seems to be that there is no such function built-in.

Since edebug instrumentation data is stored on the target symbols, I have been using the following basic function:

```
(defun ebpa/edebug-remove-all-instrumentation ()
  "Remove all edebug instrumentation by visiting each function
definition and running `eval-defun`."
  (interactive)
  (mapatoms
   (lambda (symbol)
     (when-let (pos (car-safe (get symbol 'edebug)))
       (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer pos)
         (goto-char (marker-position pos))
         (eval-defun nil))))))
```